# Unable to install python cryptography module

Tags: python

I have a python program with the line

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
```

When run with python3, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

I installed python-pip, then ran

```
pip install cryptography
pip install pycrypto
```

And I still get the same error. Any solution?

Comment: I also installed python-dev and libffi-dev, then --force-reinstall cryptography module, but it did not solve anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are multiple versions of python interpreters and pip versions present. So in order to install the cryptography package try using this

```
python -m pip install cryptography
```

This actually happened to me when I was using virtualenv so I got solution from here: [ImportError after successful pip installation - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. I used python3, so I had to install python3-pip package, then run `python3 -m pip install cryptography`

Answer (score 0):

To install **`cryptography`** you need the following packages to be installed first:-
`build-essentials`, `python-dev`, `libssl-dev`, `libffi-dev`

Simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials python3-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev
```

Then you can do:

```
pip install cryptography
```

> **Note:**
>
> - Make sure you have a `C` compiler for example, `gcc`, already installed
> - Replace `python3-dev` with `python-dev` if you are working with `python2`

*Hope this helps.*

*For more info:* [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22210069/10204932)

Namaste